# Error when exporting list to Excel by clicking Export to Excel

Tags: list, document-library, excel, export, internet-explorer

I'm trying to export a list by clicking "Export to Excel" in the List ribbon on Internet Explorer 10. I am getting error:

> "To export a list, you must have a Microsoft SharePoint
>   Foundation-compatible application".

I researched this but couldn't find a solution. I have only one version of office (2010) installed on my system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support**:

[image]

Sources:

[To export a list, you must have a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible application.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2014/02/24/to-export-a-list-you-must-have-a-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-compatible-application/)

[Export to Excel Not Working in SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2016](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/export-to-excel-not-working-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-2016/)

See more advanced in [Error: "To export a list, you must have a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible application"](http://sharepointcherie.blogspot.com.ar/2014/05/error-to-export-list-you-must-have.html)

Answer (score 1):

In case the above solution is not worked, try to Install **Service Pack 2 for Office 2010**  from

- [Office 2010 Service Pack 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687455) .